# CSS (or JS) set height of div and have the width be equal to make a squares

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

Not sure why but I am having a hard time trying to put this into a readable question but here goes.

I am trying to figure out a way to have two stacked square div's that fill the browser's height. I have searched and found a lot of ways to keep the div's square based on width but can not seem to find anything based on viewport height.

What I have so far : http://codepen.io/jointmedias/full/mxlLC

Basically, from the above example, I need the red and purple div's to always be square no matter what the height or width of the browser is.

Anyone got any tips? Thanks in advanced.

Brian

Comment: CSS to keep relative dimensions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173957/css-set-div-width-100-and-resize-keeping-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS only solution:

```
.side-top, .side-bottom {
    width: 50vh;
    height: 50vh;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/UltCombo/pen/Bbmxk)

`vh` is a viewport height percentage unit, part of [CSS3 Values and Units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths).

Support for Viewport CSS units is pretty good nowadays, see the [support table](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units).

In case you need to support IE<=8 and android stock browser, you will need a JS fallback.

Comment: OP, feel free to @ me if you need to extend the main content to fill the remaining browser width, though I guess a new question would be more appropriate in that case as there are quite a few ways to do that.

Comment: thank you for the demo and explanation worked perfect.. I would assume to make the main content to fill the remaining browser width I would just change the width from 75% to 100% right? Again thank you.

Comment: @BrianEspinosa It depends a bit on the effect you want to achieve, for example, setting main content to `100%` width means that some of it will be below the sidebar boxes. The way I'd do it to get auto-expanding main content would be using floats with vertical float clearing instead of absolute positioning for the two boxes, and the main content being a div wrapper or a block formatting context sitting at the left of the boxes.

Comment: Here's a quick illustration of the above: [pen](http://codepen.io/UltCombo/pen/fgeyh). You will have to adjust to your use case, or ask another question with the issues you find.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple jQuery-based solution that I have came up with (http://codepen.io/terrymun/pen/nEDoA):

```
$(function() {
  var $w = $(window);

  $w.resize(function() {
    $(".side-content > div")
      .height($w.height() * 0.5)
      .width($w.height() * 0.5);
    $(".main-content")
      .width($w.width() - $w.height() * 0.5);
  }).resize();
});
```

The logic behind the function is simple - firing the .resize() event when the DOM is ready (thus the chaining), and also listening to the .resize() event. I have assigned the jQuery object `$w` to `$(window)` to simplify things.

Hint: It might be a good idea to [throttle](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) the `.resize()` event, because in some browsers the event gets fired too often, and may hamper the performance of your site upon resizing.

---

I have also taken the liberty to simplify your CSS a little more:

```
.side-content > div {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
.side-top {
    background: red;
}
.side-bottom {
    background: purple;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Why is there a downvote? The author didn't ask for a non-JS solution.

Comment: Thank you.. this is actually a great solution as well. Not sure why the down-vote either but I upped it.

Answer (score -1):

Well Html and browsers are very bad at element heights (heights that are not specified in pixels, cm...), why not consider using javascript? you can do this easily with jquery:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
            //perform any resize logic here
            //I use timeout logic here so that the resizing function does
            //not repeat so many times and consume more resources than it should
            clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
            resizeTimer = setTimeout(adjustNews, 100);
        });
function adjustNews() {
        $('.yourTwoElementsByClass').css({ width: $(this).height() + "px" });
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible to do this with pure CSS. You will have to create a Javascript function that:

- Is called when the browser viewport is resized
- Retrieves the height of one of the two blocks
- Sets the width of the blocks to the retrieved height

You can also set the height of the blocks using Javascript, but you already have that fixed using CSS.