# Why am I getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, event-handling, jquery-events

My JS file is simply

```
jQuery(function ( $ ) {
    // make elements with class 'same-height-as-width' have the self-explanatory property
    $(window).resize(function ( ) {
        $('.same-height-as-width').each( function ( ) {
            var thisElement = $(this);
            thisElement.height(thisElement.width());        
        });
    });

    window.onscroll = function () {

        var body = document.body; //IE 'quirks'
        var document = document.documentElement; //IE with doctype
        document = (document.clientHeight) ? document : body;

        if (document.scrollTop == 0) {
            alert("top");
        }
    };

});
```

and the line that is causing me trouble is `var body = document.body; //IE 'quirks'`. The error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined

is printed to the console every time I scroll. And yet, when I type `document.body` into the console, the element shows up in the console, is not `undefined`. I've also tried moving the `window.onscroll` outside the j`Query(function ( $ )` but I get the same error.

Comment: By the way you can use CSS to make something the same height as its width (without knowing the width).

Comment: @Popnoodles Example would be surely appreciated, even now.

Comment: See this answer [CSS - Set Div Width 100% and Resize Keeping Aspect Ratio](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24064765/822711)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of [JavaScript variable hoisting](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-hoisting-explained--net-15092), but without confusing you to much, don't use "document" as a name for your variable